# Accessing LibreOffice Writer files via terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, python, libreoffice, python3

How do I access and edit LibreOffice Writer files with Python in Ubuntu using terminal?

Comment: By specifying the path to the writer file in whatever python function you want to use to access it. You should [edit] your question and provide more context: what do you want to achieve? What have you tried? Which problems did you encounter? If your question is only about the python programming part, you'll probably want to ask it on StackOverflow.

Comment: I found this online with a bit of googling: ["Scripting LibreOffice with Python"](https://onesheep.org/scripting-libreoffice-python/) and [automate your office tasks with Python Macros](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html)

Comment: Are you asking how to launch LibreOffice using python? Or do you want to edit .odt files without launching LibreOffice? What does "with Python [...] using terminal" mean? Are you asking how to write Python scripts that edit .odt files, or are you asking how to (laboriously) type something at a shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, I want to access LibreOffice files using terminal and make changes to odt files. @user535733

Answer (score 0):

Convert the odt to text. You can use regular "open with" in python to read, write the text file and afterwards you can convert the text file back to an 
 odt file.

Libreoffice has its own tool for this:

```
libreoffice --convert-to txt {file}.odt
```

and

```
libreoffice --convert-to odt {file}.txt
```

Python "open with"  is [chapter 7.2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) in the documentation.

Comment: It's not working @Rinzwind